# Python Discord Bot With MySQL Database Issue

Tags: python, mysql, discord

I am new to Python and general coding so I apologize for my issue.

**What The Bot Does**

- You message the bot "cargo"
- Bot responds and asks what cargo is being added
- I reply something like "melons" its added to database
- The bot then asks how many to add to the database
- The bot will then check to see if the item is already in db

**My Issue**
I can take an input of the name of supply and the amount. However they do not appear next to eachother in database. I want the bot to obtain a single value with each question.

- The supply & amount are not next to one another in database
- How do I check if the item is already in DB to prevent duplicates
- The reason I have '@' as an if statement, is again I am unsure how to create a conversation flow with discord to generate and use inputs as database entries

**The Code**

```
def handle_response(message) -> str or float or int:
    p_message = message.lower()
    if p_message == 'cargo':
        return 'What cargo is being added onboard'
    if '@' in p_message:
        sql = """INSERT INTO cargo (supplies) VALUES (%s)"""
        val = message.lower()
        cursor.execute(sql, (val,))
        conn.commit()
        return 'How many of them are being added?'
    if p_message != str:
        sql = """INSERT INTO cargo (amount) VALUES (%s)"""
        val = message.lower()
        cursor.execute(sql, (val,))
        conn.commit()
        return 'Honk Honk!! Supplies onboard!!'

    else:
        return 'something is not right'
```

**Image of Bot In use and database**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPMhn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use TinyDB with Discord bots, super easy to use. The code below is a fully functional Discord bot that will store cargo in a database and if the cargo is already present in the database it will add the new value.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import default_permissions
import asyncio
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from tinydb.operations import increment

q = Query()
db = TinyDB('./databases/cargo.json')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents, members = True, guilds = True, messages = True, guild_messages = True, message_content = True)

@bot.slash_command(name = "addcargo", description = "adds cargo")
async def addcargo(ctx, cargo, amount):

    cargo = cargo
    amount = amount
    result = db.search(q.Cargo == cargo)

    if result == []:
        db.insert({'Cargo': cargo, 'Amount': amount})
    else:  
        quantity = (result[0]['Amount'])
        sum = int(quantity)+int(amount)
        db.update({'Amount': str(sum)}, q.Cargo == cargo)
   
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I made this with the latest version of pycord and it uses the slash command /addcargo

The database would look like this:

```
{"_default": {"1": {"Cargo": "dogs", "Amount": "11"}, "2": {"Cargo": "pears", "Amount": "3"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the time and efforts, I really need to use mysql as I use it for other projects and the end goal is to use this bot for daily use with mysql in honesty. I can see why tindb has its benefits for sure so I thank you again for the info